# Advantage of a single large telescope over many small ones for optical/infrared spectroscopy?

Tags: optics, astronomy, spectroscopy, redshift, telescopes

In a thought experiment where we would like to do optical/infrared spectroscopy on distant galaxies, and in which we would like to increase as much as possible the resolution of the spectroscopy (wavelength resolution), is there an advantage of using a single large telescope over many small ones:

1. Question 1: in space?
2. Question 2: on earth? (even if the atmosphere will limit what we can do in infrared, we can still do things for low redshifts)

For example for doing spectroscopy how "better" is it to have a single 40 meter-telescope (like the ELT) instead of 1600 one-meter telescopes? (formulas/equations to help understand would be nice)

Answer (score 3):

The bigger telescope is going to be better when pushing the limits of what is possible.

Consider the scenario where you are trying to do spectroscopy of a faint, distant source, where photons are scarce. The signal to noise ratio in each pixel of your spectrum is determined by the signal you receive, which scales with telescope area, but the noise also has contributions from the readout noise of the detector.

The limits of what you can do will ultimately be determined by that detector noise and it is better to have all your signal concentrated onto one detector, with one lot of readout noise, than spread over 1600 smaller telescopes and their individual detectors.

A numerical example: Suppose the 40m telescope collects 1600 counts per spectral pixel and the detector has a readout noise of 10 electrons. The signal to noise is dominated by Poissonian shot noise and will be $\sim \sqrt{1600}$. If you now spread that signal over 1600 smaller telescopes, the signal to noise in each is dominated by the readout noise and is $\sim 1/10$. You can in principle improve that by combining the spectra from each telescope giving you a gain of $\sqrt{1600}$, but you would still be a factor of 10 worse off.

There are also other forms of systematic noise (dark noise, cosmic rays) that would be increased if using multiple detectors and so the detriment would be more than just the factor of 10 I outlined.

Comment: +1 but perhaps worth an edit to distinguish more between "telescope" and "spectrograph". I'm thinking for example of the [ESPRESSO](https://www.eso.org/sci/facilities/paranal/instruments/espresso.html) spectrograph at the VLT. It can combine light from 4 telescopes (but you could argue that in this mode it's one telescope with 4 widely separated mirrors) onto one spectrograph detector.

Comment: @KyleOman Per the article "The CTs bring the light from each telescope to the CCL through 13 optical elements, including mirrors, lenses, and prisms" and all signal comes to one detector.  This is a form of "synthetic aperture" as a photon has the choice of entering any telescope on its way to the detector, the effect is to increase spatial resolution .... but the op wants spectral resolution so ProfRobs answer dominates if multi detectors are used.